# Why does calling count on an Enumerator indefinitely hang?

Tags: arrays, ruby, enums

I spent ages debugging my code trying to find why my simple script was hanging with no error messages/warnings.

I am cycling through an Enumerator and performing a certain task depending on the value at that cycle.

### The below example is just to demonstrate how I arrived at this error (I understand this can be coded in a better way)

```
marketplaces = ["ebay","amazon","shopify"].cycle.each
complete = false

while(!complete)
  marketplace = marketplaces.next

  if marketplace == "ebay"
    // do abc
    completed = 1
  elsif marketplace == "amazon"
    // do def
    completed += 1
  elsif marketplace == "shopify"
    // do xyz
    completed += 1
  end

  // indefinetely hangs here
  if marketplaces.count == completed
    complete = true
  end
end
```

### My question:

I understand now you can't call `.count` on an Enumerator type in Ruby but why does it just hang, what's going on behind the scenes?

---

To reproduce, just create any array and turn it into an enumerator and call count on that object:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can call `count` on an `Enumerator`, `Enumerator`s are `Enumerable`s so you can count them. However, you can't count to infinity.

Comment: You are counting the number of elements of an infinite `Enumerator`. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array#cycle   [per the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle):

> Calls the given block for each element n times or forever if nil is given.

Since you haven't given an argument, it calls the block indefinitely, going through all of the values in the array and then starting from the first value again.

You can see this by executing:

```
 [1,2].cycle { |i| p i }
```

> why does it just hang

count call doesn't hang, it increments the counter for every yielded value. Since integers in Ruby can be arbitrarily large, *eventually* the count call will run out of memory and fail, but it will take a very very very long time for this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerators have two methods to determine the number of elements:

- [`count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) which counts the elements by *traversing* the collection
- [`size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-size) which *calculates* the size

`size` might return `nil` if the size cannot be calculated.

In general, `size` is much faster:

```
[1, 2].repeated_permutation(24).count  # takes some seconds
#=> 16777216

[1, 2].repeated_permutation(24).size   # returns immediately
#=> 16777216
```

and it can also handle infinite enums  just fine:

```
[1, 2].cycle.size
#=> Infinity
```